# Convert a english numeric words into some other language without writing conversion program

Tags: sql-server-2005

Suppose I have a number as 123. In words it will be **one two three**

Is it possible to convert that number words into some other language without writing a conversion program in sql server.

I tried with

```
SET LANGUAGE Italian 

declare @i int
set @i =1 

print @i
```

but it is not working..

The expected output being

```
uno due tre
```

Help needed

**NB~** Here I just set an example with Italian language. It can be Swedish, Spanish, French etc.

Comment: I don't understand. How is the number `102` different in English or Italian? Do you want Roman numerals ("CII")?

Comment: What i intended to say is that 123 is read as one two three. I want the output to be uno due tre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is an appropriate thing for the database server to be doing.  The job of the database is to return data.  Localization of strings is an application-level concern.  Really, the database should return something close to its internal representation format - in other words, '123'.  Not a string, but a number.